# My Twitter account still on another iPhone

Tags: twitter, passwords, iphone

Okay so my very nosy cousin, I trusted with my Twitter account. She would tweet things I did not like and look through my things. I was fed up and told her to delete my account. She showed me that she did, off of the app. I believed it but later she laughed and I realized she had tweeted all over again. How can I revoke her accessing my account without her knowing. We both have iPhones. I have changed my password and she was never logged out automatically like other social media sites do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to revoke access via the Web using by going into Settings, then apps. This article in the support docs goes through the process in more detail: https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170805#revoke-access-web

In there you should see "iOS by Apple", click on revoke access and this **should** log you out of all iOS device using your Twitter account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for iOS there is no option to do it remotely. You have to logout by using the same device in iOS case. Password changing is the option to logout from browser or Android but it will not work for iOS.